# Why use of many router outlet cause error?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I build an app where the home page hasn't the same html structure as the other pages. I also use mdbangular as UI framework. In order to switch template from home page to other pages I made this routing behavior (I summarized):

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { homePage: true } },
{ path: 'event-details', component: EventDetailsComponent },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { fullPage: true } },
```

Take a look at the data paramater.
In the layout file I switch between html this way:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="homePage === true">
    <router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)' (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>     
</ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="homePage === false && fullPage == false">
        <!-- JUST A SAMPLE IMAGINE EXTRA HTML-->
        <router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)' (deactivate)='onDeactivate($event)'></router-outlet>
    </ng-container>
```

When I navigate between the home page to any other pages, I will get an error which WILL BE AVOID IF I ONLY USE ONE ROUTER-OUTLET INSTEAD OF TWO.

My question is: Why do I get an error when I make use of two router-outlet instead of one? Is there a rule or something with Angular6+ I should do when I switch between router-outlet this way? Like destroy or detach the previous router-outlet before the next one?

Here's how I fetch the data parameter:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(() => {
        const routeParams = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.data;

        if (routeParams.homePage === undefined || routeParams.homePage === null) {
          this.homePage = false;
        } else {
          this.homePage = routeParams.homePage;
        }

        if (routeParams.fullPage === undefined || routeParams.fullPage === null) {
          this.fullPage = false;
        } else {
          this.fullPage = routeParams.fullPage;
        }
    });
```

Here is the [error explain with the mdbcarousel](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/carousel-issue-in-ssr-rendering/). But this is not limited to the carousel. This is why I doubt this is more an Angular thing and this is also why I ask the question here.

Thanks for any guidance,

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`router-outlet` renders the current child. 
E.g.

```
{ 
   path: 'event-details', 
   component: EventDetailsComponent,
   children: [
       { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
       { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
   ],
},
```

So depending whether your URL is `event-details/login` or `event-details/home`, `EventDetailsComponent`s `router-outlet` will render the component asked.
If you want to have different templates you got to create different routes.

I believe that the `*ngIf` is not working because angular checks routes before it checks for DOM changes. Makes sense, since it has to direct to a route before rendering the page.

In any case you should **100% not use two router-outlets** within the same component, rather rethink your approach. `data` should not be used to `*ngIf` the `router-outlet`!